# How do i remove the LIMIT with a button in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

right now i would like to make a button that removes the (LIMIT 3) from my php code, so all the rows display instead of having a limit on 3

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM artikler ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 3"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($query);


while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $titel = $row['art_titel'];
    $indhold = $row['art_indhold'];

echo "<article class='article-box'>";
echo "<div class='art-title'>$titel</div>";
echo "<div class='art-content'>$indhold</div>";
echo "<div class='art-view'><a href='pages/e-artikel.php?id=$row[art_id]'>Vis</a></div>";
echo "<div class='art-date'>".date_format(date_create($row["art_dato"]),'d/m/Y')."</div>";
echo "</article>";
}
```

I have been thinking about making a IF ELSE statement, but im not really sure on how i can do this, please make a detailed explanation im pretty new to php.

Comment: My idea is to have a button that says show all articals, instead of only three of them.

Comment: use $_GET or $_POST, implement a request for limit -> check request is given and include limit with x or no limit => basic if statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JS code:

```
<script>
    function getRecords(type){
        location.href= 'action.php?limited='+type;
    }
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<input type='button' onclick="getRecords('all')" id='submit_button' name='showall' value='Show All'/>
<input type='button' onclick="getRecords('limited')" id='submit_button' name='showlimited' value='Show Top 3'/>
```

PHP code:

```
$limited = $_GET['limited'];//As per code change it to GET
$condition = '';
if($limited == 'limited'){
    $condition = ' LIMIT 3';
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM artikler ORDER BY 1 DESC $condition";
```

Comment: Suggestion: don't use `$_REQUEST`, it's better to use specific global arrays (in this case `$_GET`)

Answer (score 1):

Add a HTML submit Button:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="showAll" name="showAll" />
</form>
```

in PHP get the button pressed code with `if/else`:

```
if(isset($_POST['showAll'])){
     $query = "SELECT * FROM artikler ORDER BY 1 DESC"; 

}else{
     $query = "SELECT * FROM artikler ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 3";
}

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
// rest of the code...
```